# connect to local mysql database from different pc's on lan

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm doing a small project where i need to acces my local database from different pc's on LAN. 
When i try acces the database from my second pc i can't. 
I have given privileges to that certain user, but when i try to acces the database I get denied.

I use apache and I have tried to change the httpd-xampp file, so it allows acces, but nothing works.

this is how i try to connect to my DB

```
$dbHost = '#';
$dbName = '#';
$dbUser = '#';
$dbPass = '#';
try {
    // attempt to connect to the database
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $dbHost . ';dbname=' . $dbName . ';charset=UTF8', $dbUser, $dbPass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // fetch results to an associative array
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING ); // show warnings, useful for debugging
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // if we get any errors, print them.
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: port forward on the database hosting node maybe

Comment: Are you sure you've given correct permissions and configured MySQL for remote connections? Does your firewall (at every point: local machines and office network) allow the connections? What error messages do you get?

Comment: When i load the php-site, it says that the destination pc denied my acces.

Comment: Can you show an example of the `CREATE USER` queries you use to grant access? You have to specify the host. For example,   `CREATE USER 'lassejoe'@'localhost' ...` won't work for other machines. You need to mention the hosts. For example `CREATE USER 'lassejoe'@'192.168.41.*' ...` or some other host specification.

Comment: I have made an user "lass93" with a auto-gen password which has localhost.

Comment: The only reason i used "#" is so you couldn't see password ect.